# Is it possible to change the message within a repeating IOS notification in react native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently working in react native for the first time, trying to create an iPhone app. it's been going well so far, but I've come across a slight limitation that I'm not sure I can workaround.

I want to be able to randomly send the user a notification a couple of times throughout the day, I've learned that I could use "repeatType" within my "localNotificationSchedule" function to set up a recurring notification message, but the problem with this is the notification repeats the same message over and over, and I want these messages to be random. is there a way about doing this?

I'm using local push notifications, and these two packages:

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

https://github.com/react-native-push-notification/ios

Comment: If you don't want to repeat the same message then don't use repeat. Set up a scheduled job wherever you're sending the notifications from and make a new push every time.

Comment: thank you for such a quick response. I'm sending the notifications locally, so from the app itself. this seems to limit me from having a system that automatically sends notifications every day, as no code will be run while the app is closed. is it safe to assume that figuring out remote push notifications is the way forward?

Comment: Yes probably. Unless you never need to send a push when the app is closed for some reason. Then I suppose you could keep sending them from the client. The strategy would be something like 1. set up an interval that checks local storage for the last time you sent a notification and if it's been long enough, send a new one, then 2. save the current time as the last notification time.

Comment: ah, I see. thank you for the help! :)